# Como retornar a variável da função em Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, front-end

Olá Gostaria de retornar a variável nomeestado para dentro de uma outra função. Como que eu faço isso? A variável retornada no retornaEndereco está undefined.

```
  function retornaEndereco()
  {
  $('.informacoes-perfil-endereco').css('display','none');
  var parseResult = "";
  var itemHTML = "";
  var resultadoBairro = "";
  var getEnderecoLogado = sessionStorage.getItem("dadosendereco");
  var quantidadeEndereco = parseResult.length;
  var listaEnderecos = $(".informacoes-perfil-endereco .box-content");
  parseResult = JSON.parse(getEnderecoLogado);

  if (parseResult == null)
  {
    console.log('Não há informações de endereço cadastradas');
  }
  else
  {
    $('.atualizar-cadastro-endereco').css('display','none');
    $('.informacoes-perfil-endereco').css('display','block');

    parseResult.forEach(function(item)
    {

      if (item.bairroendereco == "Selecione...")
      {
        resultadoBairro = "Não há bairro para a localidade";
      }
      else
      {
        resultadoBairro = item.bairroendereco;
      }

      // retorna as cidades em o id da cidade
    RETORNAR AQUI  var nomeestado = estadoEditar(item.estadoendereco);
      var nomecidade = cidadeEditar(item.estadoendereco, item.cidadeendereco);

    //  alert(nomeestado);

      itemHTML += "<div class='cependerecotexto'>Cep: <strong>" + item.cependereco  + "</strong></div>";
      itemHTML += "<div class='logradouroenderecotexto'>Logradouro: <strong>" + item.logradouroendereco + "</strong></div>";
      itemHTML += "<div class='numerologradourotexto'>Número: <strong>" + item.numeroendereco + "</strong></div>";
      itemHTML += "<div class='complementologradourotexto'>Complemento: <strong>" + item.complementoendereco + "</strong></div>";
      itemHTML += "<div class='estadocomplementotexto'>Estado: <strong>" + nomeestado + "</strong></div>";
      itemHTML += "<div class='cidadecomplementotexto'>Cidade: <strong>" + nomecidade + "</strong></div>";
      itemHTML += "<div class='bairrocomplementotexto'>Bairro: <strong>" + resultadoBairro + "</strong></div><br />";
      itemHTML += "<a href='' title='Atualizar o Endereço' class='btn-atualizar-endereco-seg-parte' style='font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px; text-decoration: underline;'>Atualizar o Endereço</a>";

    });

    listaEnderecos.append(itemHTML);
  }
}

 function estadoEditar(idEstado)
  {
    var id_estadoselecionado = "";
    var nomeestado = "";
    $.ajax({
      url: urlBase + "estado",
      method: 'GET'
    }).done(function(retorno)
    {
      $.each(retorno.data, function (i, item)
      {
        idestadoSelecionado = item.estado_id;
        if (idestadoSelecionado == idEstado)
        {
          nomeestado = item.nome;
        }
      });
    RETORNAR LA NA OUTRA FUNÇÃO        return nomeestado;
    }).fail(function(data)
    {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

// melhorei apenas a tabulação

Comment: não consigo ler a primeira parte do código, esta meio ruim. Arruma ae que eu te ajudo nessa!

Comment: Como que edita a pergunta?

Comment: Ajustei aqui, vou fazer uma resposta pra você

Comment: ok. Fico no aguardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo o que eu vi aqui, literalmente você não vai conseguir retornar o resultado dessa forma, pois quando você faz o return dentro do método do jQuery, ele esta retornando sim mas para o escopo do método do jQuery não da sua  function estadoEditar(idEstado), sacou? (é meio confuso mesmo de entender isso)

Hoje em dia temos recursos na nova versão do JavaScript que nos dão soluções assíncronas, sim esse seu problema é um problema assíncrono.

Por exemplo nossas [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Mas acredito que você não está usando recursos novos do JS, então recomendo que você faça um callback para adquirir o valor que você precisa

**Código**

Ao invés de simplesmente passar o id do estado para a função, altere para a seguinte forma:

```
function estadoEditar(idEstado, callback)
```

feito isso, modifique o código do seu AJAX para a seguinte forma:

onde esta:

```
return nomeestado;
```

troque para

```
callback(nomeestado)
```

para usar este método, tente fazer da seguinte forma:

```
estadoEditar(idEstado, function (nomeEstado) {
    console.log(nomeEstado)
    // após pegar o nome do estado, continue sua lógica aqui dentro
})
```

Espero que isso te ajude!

Comment: Ok deu certo. Valeu

Comment: Aee, marca como respondido!